# strange behavior of SASS

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Yesterday I start using SASS for my css and already now regrets. I can't figuret what's is wrong:

global.scss:

```
@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass/css3/user-interface";

@mixin gradient-brown-transparent(){
  @include background(linear-gradient(top, rgba(46,37,31,0.9) 15%, rgba(34,26,21,0.9) 65%));}
```

main.scss:

```
@import 'global';

#main{
  @include display-flex;
  @include flex-basis(350);
  @include gradient-brown-transparent;}
```

Now everything works perfect until I edit one of the file where I import GLOBAL.SCSS. When I do it, SCSS generate linear gradient with color: rgba(46,37,31,**0**) [changes alpha to 0].
GLOBAL.SCSS generate correct css file only when I save it directly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, what version of Compass and Sass are you using?

Comment: try `@include background(linear-gradient(top, rgba(46,37,31,.9) 15%, rgba(34,26,21,.9) 65%))` - that is, without leading zero - maybe the version of sass&compass you use are a buggy version, dunno. But I couldn't reproduce either using both sass/compass in `--pre` versions

Comment: @cimmanon thank, you give me a clue where to search issue.
And of course I find: https://github.com/mhs/scout-app/issues/41.
What's a problem ehh.....